# TypeOrm - Custom Many to Many not pulling relation data

Tags: typeorm

because I don't want use cascade to update the join table and I want custom columns, I've created a custom many to many relationship. However when I query the relation it only provides the values in the join table and doesn't pull the relation data.

User

```
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => UserArtistFollowing,
    (userArtistFollowing) => userArtistFollowing.user
  )
  following: UserArtistFollowing[];
}
```

Artist

```
@Entity('artist')
export class Artist {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => UserArtistFollowing,
    (userArtistFollowing) => userArtistFollowing.artist
  )
  usersFollowing: UserArtistFollowing[];

}
```

UserArtistFollowing

```
@Entity('userArtistFollowing')
export class UserArtistFollowing {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  userId!: string;

  @Column()
  artistId!: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => User,
    (user) => user.following
  )
  user!: User;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Artist,
    (artist) => artist.usersFollowing
  )
  artist!: Artist;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

Query

```
    const user = await getManager()
      .getRepository(Models.User)
      .findOne({
        where: { id: id },
        relations: ['following'],
      });
```

So that query only provides the id, userId, artistId, but not the Artist array of objects (which is the data I need).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After further testing, turns out you can use find -> relations with these kinds of custom many to many relationships. You just have to specify the relation in dotted notation for nested relations.

```js
      const user = await getManager()
        .getRepository(Models.User)
        .findOne({
          where: { id },
          relations: [
// you have to specify the join table first (following) to retrieve the columns in the join table
            'following',
// then you use dotted notation to get the relation from the join table
            'following.artist',
// another example of a deeply nested relation
            'favourites',
            'favourites.song',
            'favourites.song.supportingArtists',
            'favourites.song.supportingArtists.artist',
          ],
        });
```

You can also use join with a nested leftJoinAndSelect, but its more tedious.

```js
    const user = await getManager()
      .getRepository(Models.User)
      .findOne({
        where: { id },
        join: {
          alias: 'user',
          leftJoinAndSelect: {
            following: 'user.following',
            artists: 'following.artist',
          },
        },
      });
```

Here is the updated entities

UserArtistFollowing

```js
@Entity('userArtistFollowing')
export class UserArtistFollowing {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: string;

  @PrimaryColumn()
  artistId: string;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => User,
    (user) => user.following
  )
  user!: User;

  @ManyToOne(
    () => Artist,
    (artist) => artist.usersFollowing
  )
  artist!: Artist;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt!: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt!: Date;
}
```

Artist

```js
@Entity('artist')
export class Artist {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => UserArtistFollowing,
    (userArtistFollowing) => userArtistFollowing.artist
  )
  usersFollowing: UserArtistFollowing[];
}
```

User

```js
@Entity('user')
export class User {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  id: string;

  @OneToMany(
    () => UserArtistFollowing,
    (userArtistFollowing) => userArtistFollowing.user
  )
  following: UserArtistFollowing[];
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem and solve it a different way. Question though. How would select artist id? Thats my problem when I used this query. you cant select other attributes of artist

Comment: Can you post the way you solved it? Not too sure how to narrow down by artist Id on the relation. I assume there's a where you can use somewhere but I havent found that yet.

Comment: @aRtoo [From the Docs:](https://typeorm.io/#/find-options) **Querying a column from an embedded entity should be done with respect to the hierarchy in which it was defined.** So I think you can just use a nested where query? Not sure if that accomodates relations

Comment: or maybe subqueries? https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/using-subqueries

Comment: @rt_I tried that bro. I had question about that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61113589/how-to-select-a-specific-column-in-typeorm-many-to-many-relationship) but I think I read somewhere that you cant select any sub realtion. its a TODO for now. I just forgot the link, But to get attributes from joins I used querybuilder

Comment: I think you read it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52246722/how-to-query-a-many-to-many-relation-with-typeorm

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the artist model fully hydrated, you could try setting `eager: true` in your RelationOptions.

https://typeorm.io/#/eager-and-lazy-relations/eager-relations

If you don't want that, then your solution makes sense.

Comment: I thought eager meant you didnt have to specify the relation to load it, as in you would just use find() with no relations specified. Not sure that would work here.

From the docs
const questionRepository = connection.getRepository(Question);. 

// questions will be loaded with its categories. 
const questions = await questionRepository.find();

Comment: Confirming that eager: true makes the relation load automatically with a find query and no further params (no join or relations: [])

Comment: I believe setting `eager: true` on the relations of your join table would have exactly the result you were looking for.
`@ManyToOne(
    () => Artist,
    (artist) => artist.usersFollowing,
    { eager: true }
  )
  artist!: Artist;`

Now this query 
    `const user = await getManager()
      .getRepository(Models.User)
      .findOne({
        where: { id: id },
        relations: ['following'],
      });`

will populate your artists relation without needing additional subqueries or joins.

Comment: Ugh, comments aren't a very nice way to include code, but what you want is to add `{ eager: true }` to your join table mappings and then your original query will work.